# Protocol handler is opening alternative browser but repeating endlessly

Tags: protocols, regedit

I have a registry key for opening a link in myBrowser from Firefox and Chrome. But it keeps opening the same link over and over again... 60 tabs and more!

Set up as a "protocol handler" the registry key was added to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT...

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mybrowser\URL Protocol 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mybrowser\shell\open\command\"C:\Program Files\MyBrowser\mybrowser.exe" "%1"
```

URL Protocol is blank.

Then to test, I open Firefox or Chrome and visit my test page which has a hyperlink like...

```
<a href="mybrowser://example.com/page.html">test</a>
```

This launches MyBrowser ok which loads the nominated page ok, but then it keeps repeating that action endlessly... resulting in 60 tabs and more being opened.